# Issues with migrating Mailbox records from one CRM to another CRM organization using kingswaysoft

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, data-migration, kingswaysoft

I am migrating data from one CRM organization to another CRM organization. I am facing issues in migrating mailbox records. When User is created in Source CRM it creates two mailboxes and I am trying to migrate these two mailboxes to target CRM but I am getting error in migrating one of the mailbox from source to target, out of the two mailboxes created. The failure mailbox gives error saying:

> [Dynamics CRM Destination [305]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message:
>
> "System.Exception: Error(s) occurred when processing the batch: [1] [GUID of record] CRM service call returned an error: An e-mail address is a required field in case of forward mailbox.  (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v8.1.0.6275 - DtsDebugHost, v12.0.2000.8)"

I have checked that the mailbox in source does not have `IsForwardmailbox` flag set true. But it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

We believe we had a conversation through our Support channel. CRM will automatically create mailbox records once you create the queue or user records, in which case you may not need to work with mailbox entity directly. If you have any other questions, please feel free to reach out.

Comment: yes, we had communicated and it helped also, thanks for your support :)

Comment: Your're very welcome, Manish! If you have any other questions, please feel free to let us know. :)